# Windows Explorer multiple folder instances

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, taskbar

I use Windows 7 and I have created shortcuts for some of the folders I use most frequently in order to place them on taskbar for easy access to them. For example, I have folder Favorites pinned to the taskbar with the command **%windir%\explorer.exe "C:\Users\Username\Favorites"** and I did the same with two other folders.The problem is that clicking the folder shortcuts  I created on the taskbar (or pressing keyboard shortcut for them) opens new instances of the same folder in Windows Explorer instead of minimizing/restoring the opened folder window, as it is the default behaviour of the Windows Explorer taskbar shortcut. When I add the same folder path to the default Windows Explorer taskbar shortcut it normally restores/minimizes the same window, but the same doesn't happen with the added folder shortcuts. Why does this happen and can I get those shortcuts opening only one instance of the folder and minimize the window when clicked again?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Try creating a batch file that says `start "" "C:\Users\Username\Favorites"` (or, alternatively, `start "" "%UserProfile%\Favorites"`) and pinning it to the taskbar. (You can omit the empty pair of quotation marks if you don’t put quotes around the directory.) Or just say `cmd /c start "" "%UserProfile%\Favorites"`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Scott. I've tried, it opens the folder but I can't pin .bat file to the taskbar.

Comment: But what about the second part of my answer? If you can pin an **explorer.exe** command (with arguments) to the taskbar, why can’t you do the same with a **cmd.exe** command?

Comment: Sorry Scott, it's late here and I don't know much about these things so I did it wrong :) It works now, I did it with  C:\Windows\explorer.exe C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Favorites.bat and the folder activates from the taskbar but it won't minimize once in the foreground when I click again on the taskbar icon.